# Sentinel KQL JSON with Dynamic Label

Tags: json, kql, sentinel

I'm experimenting with Microsoft Sentinel and trying to understand how to parse JSON elements.  One experiment is that I've wired my house with temperature and humidity sensors and fed them in, now the difficulty is the parsing... they're syslog events with a Message containing JSON as shown below.

```
SENSOR = 
{
    "ZbReceived":
    {
        "0x03FA":
        {
            "Device":"0x03FA",
            "Name":"2_Back_Bedroom",
            "Humidity":71.66,"Endpoint":1,
            "LinkQuality":66
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the devices include the device ID as a label in the JSON, which makes it hard for me to figure out how to extract all the fields.  There are 8 sensors, so repeating this for every one of them seems inefficient, but maybe it's necessary?

Is there a way I could extract the values from 8 different sensors?  I've tried .[0]. and other variants, but no luck.

```
print T = dynamic('SENSOR = {"ZbReceived":{"0x03FA":{"Device":"0x03FA","Name":"2_Back_Bedroom","Humidity":71.66,"Endpoint":1,"LinkQuality":66}}}')
| mv-expand humidity = parse_json(substring(T, 9)).ZbReceived.["0x03FA"].Humidity
| mv-expand device = parse_json(substring(T, 9)).ZbReceived.["0x03FA"].Device
| mv-expand name = parse_json(substring(T, 9)).ZbReceived.["0x03FA"].Name
| mv-expand battery = parse_json(substring(T, 9)).ZbReceived.["0x03FA"].Battery
| mv-expand temperature = parse_json(substring(T, 9)).ZbReceived.["0x03FA"].Temperature
```

Comment: What's the point of storing the data as dynamic if it's not a valid JSON? Do you really need the "SENSOR = " part?

Comment: @DavidדודוMarkovitz it's part of the syslog message. I'm leaving "SENSOR =" in because the solution for the problem will have to parse it out. It's very possible I'm misusing the dynamic keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick explanation:
Under

```
print T = dynamic('SENSOR = {"ZbReceived":{"0x03FA":{"Device":"0x03FA","Name":"2_Back_Bedroom","Humidity":71.66,"Endpoint":1,"LinkQuality":66}}}')
| parse tostring(T) with  "SENSOR = " sensor:dynamic
| project device = sensor.ZbReceived[tostring(bag_keys(sensor.ZbReceived)[0])]
| evaluate bag_unpack(device)
```

| Device | Endpoint | Humidity | LinkQuality | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0x03FA | 1 | 71.66 | 66 | 2_Back_Bedroom |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA2WPQUvDQBCF74L/YZhLsxBKqhBhoYcWKx6kYtuTpYRtdqhrmt2wu4mGmv/uJtV68Dbz%20ObNe5VV2sMGpiBbLUqVR6P1Yrl%20XgXlhK/7FeWkGpLIT5h8JrcPs366p0blhPxXinEpyn6/yeYiL7I5SWtMGfTHulRS%20Rb53WScpjEutKxM%20Il8EuOT0sVLLY4DkKZd143Y9dUXVMI6Am%20cD/EO0YbBh/JvAHjJhuBIO2P5T%20zhypp3yj3IIV2Azsj4r8X2YrkXh6yg1kX/GLZNdmzX%201EjjrXwBD1c6yo0i87e7BtBp39oNwEAAA==)

P.S.
For clarity, the line with the *project* operator could be replaced with the following 2 lines:

```
| extend device_id = tostring(bag_keys(sensor.ZbReceived)[0]) // e.g., 0x03FA
| project device = sensor.ZbReceived[device_id]
```

Comment: hmm... I'm going to have to read a little to understand why this works.  It's excellent, thank you.